# Laravel auto-retry Notification on fail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-horizon

I use Laravel Horizon and am putting Notifications in a row as follows:

```
# Notifies the user that the transfer was made
$transfer->user->notify((new ConfirmedTransfer($transfer))->queue('default'));
```

The problem is that when an error occurs, the Horizon does not give a retry automatically.
How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jobs :

read more here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#generating-job-classes

```
class TransferJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $tries = 5;

}
```